# Преобразование 24 часа времени в 12 часов (PM / AM)

Tags: javascript

Необходимо преобразовать время из 24-и часового формата в 12-и часовой формат.
Вот мой код, я использовал последнюю строку кода из интернета, что преобразует 24 часа в 12, но синтаксис `(hour >= 12)? hour - 12: hour;` мне не понятен, почему просто не использовать функцию с conditional statement if? И зачем нужен такой формат?

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay();
var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday    ","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
var hour = today.getHours();
var minute = today.getMinutes();
var second = today.getSeconds();
var prepand = (hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM ";
hour = (hour >= 12)? hour - 12: hour;
```

Comment: можно просто % 12 использовать. остаток от деления на 12.

Comment: В am/pm 0ч нужно заменять на 12ч

Answer (score 4):

Это тернарный оператор. Для лучшего понимания почитайте тут:
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тернарная_условная_операция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Безотносительно к определённому языку программирования тернарную операцию можно определить так:

```
логическое выражение ? выражение 1 : выражение 2
```

Алгоритм работы операции следующий:

1. Вычисляется логическое выражение.
2. Если логическое выражение истинно, то вычисляется значение выражения "выражение 1", в противном случае — значение выражения "выражение 2".
3. Вычисленное значение возвращается.

В Вашем случае:

```
hour = (hour >= 12)? hour - 12: hour;
```

разворачивается в:

```
if (hour >= 12) 
    hour = hour - 12;
else
    hour = hour;
```

Как видите это требует большего кол-ва кода, требует больше времени на понимания происходящего. Для сокращения кода и используют тернарный оператор ?:

Comment: `"hour = hour;"`. Во-втором у вас что-то пошло не так. Там можно просто сделать так: `if (hour >= 12) hour = hour - 12;`

Comment: @Yuri, это не живой код, цель показать как разворачивается тернарный оператор в обычный if

Comment: Та я это понял, но вы написали `Заменить можно на`. Если уж заменять то на тот)) Или не `Заменить можно на`, а `Это выражение равно этому`) Но в любом случая ловите +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

`hour = (hour >= 12)? hour - 12: hour;`

Тернарный оператор имеет вид:

```
 Условие ? РезультатЕслиИстинно : РезультатЕслиЛожно
```

Т.е. код выше, дословно обозначает:

```
  if (hour >= 12) {
    hour = hour - 12;
  } else {
    hour = hour;
  }
```

Из-за бессмысленной ветки `else` вариант `if (hour >= 12) hour -= 12` может быть более предпочтительным.

---

*Этот код выдаст вам время `0:15 am` для четверти первого ночи, в то время как должно быть `12:15 am`.*

Предлагаю воспользоваться вот такой заменой:

```
hour= hour % 12 || 12;
```

Здесь мы берём остаток от деления на 12, но если он равен нулю результат равен 12.

Answer (score 2):

А не проще-ли использовать [стандартный функционал вывода даты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)?

```js
var date = new Date();

// Запрашиваем нужный формат вывода даты
var options = { 
      weekday: 'long', 
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long', 
      day: 'numeric' , 
      hour:  'numeric', 
      hour12 : true, // время в AM-PM формате
      minute : 'numeric'
};
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', options));
```

Answer (score 1):

Тернарный оператор не есть по сути заменой условному оператору if. 
Его использование оправдывается при встраивании небольшых условных веток прямо в выражения. Если вам нужно уже сделать условие вне выражения, лучше использовать if...else. То-есть в вашем случае код вида

```
if(hour >= 12){
  hour = hour - 12;
}else{
  hour = hour;
}
```

превращается в `hour = (hour >= 12)? hour - 12: hour;` .

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()` с локалем en-US.

Например, так: `date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US')`, что даст время в формате, к примеру "1:00:00 PM"

Подробнее здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString